# Show that $ \nabla . ({\bf T}^T {\bf v}) = {\bf T} : \nabla {\bf v} + {\bf v} \cdot (\nabla . {\bf T})$

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors

Here is my feeble attempt:

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\nabla .({\bf T}^T {\bf v}) & = \frac{\partial {\bf T}_{ji}}{\partial x_j} {\bf v}_i + {\bf T}_{ji}  \frac{\partial {\bf v}_{i}}{\partial x_j} \\
& = (\nabla . {\bf T}^T) \cdot {\bf v} + {\bf T}^T \, \nabla {\bf v}
\end{aligned}\end{equation} \\
$$

Source: page 2 of these [lecture notes](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/112103167/module4/lec27.pdf#page=2).

Comment: You are taking the divergence of a vector, so the result is a scalar. What made you think the result should be a vector?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Of course you are right. I've made the edit. (Thanks for your patience.)

Comment: No worries! but now it looks like you are already done haha.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz am I done? I've modified the question and my final step does not seem to resemble the RHS of the expression that I am trying to prove.

Comment: Oh, you mean the transposes? Didn't notice that before, sorry.
Yes, that issue may come from differences in the definition of the gradient of a tensor. Are you following a book or a set of notes? so we can check at the definitions and look for the problem.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I am following the conventions in these here [notes](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/112/103/112103167/)

Comment: I'm reading the notes. Give me a sec and I'll try to spot what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of unwrapping the definitions very carefully. Even if you are already familiar with the objects, it is always convenient to go back to the definitions because different authors have conflicting conventions and this often results in different formulas.

From module 1 lecture 4, we have $R:S=R_{ij}S_{ij}$.

Also $Te_j=T_{ij}e_i$, so
$$Tv={\textstyle\sum}Te_jv_j={\textstyle\sum}T_{ij}e_iv_j,$$
This means the components of $Tv$ are given by $(Tv)_i=T_{ij}v_j$. Thus we have $(T^tv)_i=T_{ji}v_j$.

From module 2 lecture 2, we have

- $\nabla G=\partial_kG_{ij}e_i\otimes e_j\otimes e_k$, so the compontents of $\nabla G$ are given by
  $$(\nabla G)_{ijk}=\partial_kG_{ij}$$
  (the new index is put at the last position).
- $\nabla v = \partial_jv_ie_i\otimes e_j$, so the components of $\nabla v$ are given by
  $$(\nabla v)_{ij}=\partial_jv_i$$
  (again, the new index is put at the last position).
- $\nabla \cdot G = \partial_jG_{ij}e_i$, so the components of $\nabla\cdot G$ are given by
  $$(\nabla\cdot G)_i=(\nabla G)_{ijj}=\partial_jG_{ij}$$
  (the derivative is summed over with the second index of $G$).

Puting all of this together, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla \cdot (T^tv) &= \partial_i(T^tv)_i \\
&=\partial_i(T_{ji}v_j) \\
&=\partial_iT_{ji}v_j+T_{ji}\partial_iv_j \\
&=(\nabla\cdot T)_jv_j+T_{ji}(\nabla v)_{ji} \\
&=(\nabla\cdot T)\cdot v+T :\nabla v
\end{aligned}$$

as you wanted. Hope this helps.